# Path Model with (endogenous) Treatment - which model?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, model, structural-equation-modeling, treatment-effect

I have collected data on the intention to create a new business of my students.

I measured it before the course (t1) and after it (t2). I have data on their absenteeism in class and the time they spent on the online platform. My hypothesis is that following my course will modify their attitude toward new business ventures and thus their intention to create a new business.

The hypothesized model is as follow:
[image: Hypothesized Model]

All variables are continuous. What is difficult is that the model includes both panel and structural equation modeling features.

Do you know a class of model that could accommodate this?

In addition, absenteeism and time spent on the online course are probably endogeneous. I would be very interested, if you know of a way to treat this additional issue.

Any pointer would be much appreciated - Thank you very much in advance!

(The question was previously posted without luck on [StataList](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1512548-path-model-with-endogenous-treatment-which-model-which-command))

Comment: The path model isn't clear (to me). Typically, a box represents a single variable.  Attitude(t1, t2) is two variables (isn't it)? You have time spent on online course predicting attitude (t1), but attitude t1 happens before time spent on course so this is predicting backwards in time.

Comment: The model is clearer if all your arrows point from left to right, not backwards.

Comment: Thank you for the direction of arrows, I will try to do something clearer next time.

Comment: Attitude (t1,t2) is the same variable measured at two points in time. I displayed it as a single variable as I use long format (in wide format, it would be two variables indeed).

Comment: Regarding time spent on online course, I code it as 0 in t1, before the course started, so that it does not predict backward in time. I am open to other suggestions though!

Comment: Change your data and conceptualization of it to wide format. This will make the causal relations much clearer and then you can simply estimate the model using a structural equation modeling software like `gsem` in Stata.

Comment: I think you need time in the variable as a model.  How will you be handing the non-independence?

Comment: This is not the kind of model I really understand. If something is zero at t1, it has no variance and can't explain anything.